# GetPreSignedUrl and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The presigned urls to S3 files we produce are working OK for a while and then we get a error message:

```
<Error>
<Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
...
</Error>
```

We have a ASP.NET MVC web application running on elastic beanstalk under an IAM role and are creating the links with the GetPresignedUrl() api call. The expiry date is 2 years away so I think the reason the links are expiring is that ["any URLs using IAM role keys will expire when that role key expires"](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=584633&#584633).

What is the best way to create presigned urls from elastic beanstalk web applications that won't expire when a new version of the application is deployed?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've come up with is to create a user that has readonly access to the S3 objects I want to provide signed links to. When creating signed links I use the new user to create the client for making the GetPresignedUrl() call.

```
AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKeyForPresignedUrls,
                AwsSecretAccessKeyForPreSignedUrls, region);
```

Not very pretty as I now have the keys accessible to the web app and if the keys are compromised and I have to revoke them, all the old presigned urls will cease to work. I'm open to other solutions.